# Calling a Method After a Controller Action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I used to believe that the following method would be invoked after all controller methods are done at the end:

```
protected override void EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Now all override methods are called and then, controller methods are invoked. Do you know what override method is invoked after all methods?

Comment: Perhaps an action filter can do whatever you want to do ?

Comment: Could you provide me an example?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I want to add something to ViewBag at the end of all controller methods. The item to be added may vary for each method.

Comment: vary like what ? Where do you get that data you want to add to viewbag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use action filter it will be called every time any method execute. You can filter it by matching method name.

```
 public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnResultExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }

      public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
           Log("OnResultExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
      }


      private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
      {
           var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
           var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
           var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName, controllerName, actionName);
           Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
      }

 }
```

For more details please visit : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs